# Keeping cassandra data model in sync after updates

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, datastax

I have several tables in a SQL Server database and am making the arduous transition to [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/).

The concept of Cassandra and the extreme denormalization I think is a great idea and well worth the cost. I have also been over almost every [data modelling exercise](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling) I can find for Cassandra and think I have a very firm grasp of that concept. [This one was very helpful](https://academy.datastax.com/courses/ds220-data-modeling).

The major problem I am having is the concept of how to keep everything in sync.
For instance if I had the following tables it seems like a major pain to update everything. Honestly it is kind of been a nightmare trying to keep track of everything. I am sure there will be orphaned data somewhere just screaming for attention.

```
TableA, TableAByX, TableAByY, TableAByZ

TableX, TableXByY, TableXByZ.
```

If I update TableA I of course have to update the ByX, ByY, and ByZ tables.
However in the extreme case if all the tables had something common like users first name, which was updated, how could I easily and accuractly ensure everything was updated?

The users firstname could be in 20 tables all with various partition keys.
I would need to do a few reads just so I can get the partition keys to update the tables.

Are there any systems or design patterns to make this easier?

Answer (score 3):

Your writer process will be taking care of that. Most probably you'd want at first to write the to a persistent log like Kafka (so that you can acknowledge the change to the users quickly) and after that various consumers subscribed to the update would fix the dependent views.

Pattern name is [CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html).

If for some reason you'll be having multiple partition keys for a user, you'll still want some kind of way of computing / retrieving those from his user key (if maintaining those multiple tables in sync is important for you).

--

Not related to your question but Another bit which you will discover is that schema migrations are getting tricky as the database grows - you can have some rows migrated / others not so it's cool to have them versioned and application code knowledgeable of how to deal with multiple versions of the schema.

Also for having those performed well you might want to have Hadoop or some way to run distributed queries / updates.

Comment: Basically I am trying to update everything in crud type methods. However subscribing to change notifications sounds like it could be a lot easier and more logical.